# How to create new column in Dataframe using condition on existing columns?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Trying to create the new column in my dataframe based on the below condition:

```py
dataFrame01['final'] = dataFrame01.apply(lambda x: x['Name'] if x['Eval'] == 'NAN' else x['Eval'], axis=1)
```

but every time only `ELSE` block is getting executed I mean values from else condition as getting populated but not from `IF` conditions.
Please help and let me know what mistake I am doing here.

Comment: Difficult to answer unless you share the actual data in the pandas dataframe.

Comment: For the next time, please spend a minute to see how to properly format your code (done it for you this time). Also, this is a standard `pandas` question, and it has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: is your data string `NAN` or `np.nan`? Also check for leading/trailing white spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say without seeing the data. It appears as though the below expression is not getting evaluated.

```
x['Eval'] == 'NAN'
```

As a hunch, check that you are specifying your NaN correctly. In Pandas, missing values are typically specified as np.nan. One way to evaluate missing values in Pandas is with pd.isnull(). Thus, the code would look something like this:

```
dataFrame01['final'] = dataFrame01.apply(lambda x: x['Name'] if pd.isnull(x['Eval']) else x['Eval'], axis=1)
```